# in Kotlin ArrayAdapter need (Context context,int resource) as parameter but i want as a string in the ArrayList how h can do that?

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

```
class Word(var mDefultTranslation: String, var mArabicTranslation: String ) {
      fun Word (defultTranslation : String , arabicTranslation : String  ){
          mDefultTranslation = defultTranslation
          mArabicTranslation = arabicTranslation
      } 
}

val words = arrayListOf<Word>()
words.add( Word("one","two" ))  
val wordAdapter = WordAdapter (this, word??)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`, something like this might get you started:

```
    val adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<Word>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, words) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
            val text1 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
            val text2 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2) as TextView
            text1.setText(words[position].mDefultTranslation)
            text2.setText(words[position].mArabicTranslation)
            return view
        }
    }
    listview.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: thanks it is work .. how i can add image to this code

Comment: That's a different question. Maybe you could learn from some of the many excellent tutorials available on the internet, like http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/listview-images-example-kotlin/ or https://www.raywenderlich.com/186976/android-listview-tutorial-2

Answer (score 0):

Put in third param into your `WordAdapter`.

```
class WordAdapter(context: Context, @LayoutRes resource: Int, private val wordList: ArrayList<Word>) : ArrayAdapter<Word>(context, resource)
```